# Why did not JSON change after I added new fields to POJO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

I have added new fields to POJO expecting to find them in response in my Spring Boot application. It is a simple POJO with Lombok annotations:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Responce implements AsyncResponse, Serializable {
    private String resultCode;
    private String errorCode; // added field

public Responce(String resultCode) {
    this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }
}
```

In my service method I have created object and then used a setter for added extra field errorCode:

```
Responce response = new Responce("0");
responce.setErrorCode("777");
```

But I still receive a JSON with one field:

```
{
    resultCode: "0"
}
```

How I can force to include new field?

UPD:
AsyncResponse looks like this

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    String getResultCode();
    void setResultCode(String resultCode);

    String getErrorCode(); // added getter
    void setErrorCode(String errorCode); // added setter
}
```

Comment: can you show this `AsyncResponse` class ? or all jackson annotations used on  `Responce` and `AsyncResponse`

Comment: Did you try the clean and re-build. ? or try something else except `errorCode`

Comment: You are using the embedded tomcat of spring boot? Can you verify if the war ou jar generated on the compile are updated?

Comment: @Deadpool there are no annotations in POJO on a class level used except mentioned. There are no annotations in AsyncResponce as well.

Comment: @abs_dev it is a tomcat, true. We use Jenkins in our delivery pipeline, so yes jar is updated as far as I know.

Comment: Jenkins does that. Do you mean write new class? It should be a solution, I haven't tried, but doesn't seems proper from OOP perspective.

Comment: No i mean add another variable with a different name and check whether it works or not.

Comment: @ReshanPubudu I do believe it will give same result, because there is a problem with serialisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a filter set up in application.yml in gateway module which hadn't  mentioned fields in fieldsToRetain parameter.